# Screen window title reverts after running a command on my new machine

Tags: gnu-screen, window-title

I use screen with a configuration that allows me to see the name of the tabs on the bottom of the screen.  I've used this configuration for many years, on many different hosts.

I installed screen on a CentOS 7 machine.  I use this `.screenrc` on another CentoOS machine, and it works as expected.  The `.screenrc` is being used on the new CentOS machine, I can tell by the way the window looks (colors, bar at the bottom).  But one thing is not working as expected.  I can change the window title by pressing control-A, A, and typing in the title.  However, on the new CentOS machine, the old (default, e.g. bash) title will come back after I've exited a program, vim for instance.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `xterm`, `screen` can save/restore the title using two different methods:

- control sequences for explicitly setting and getting the title
- control sequences for stacking/unstacking the title.

Both sets of control sequences can be disabled using the [`disallowedWindowOps`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:disallowedWindowOps) resource, and either set could explain the behavior reported.